# How does the season-penalty work?

Tags: kittens-game

How does the season-effect to production work, exactly?

For example, it says [-75%] during winter. Does that affect the Catnip-Fields, the Farmerkittens or everything?

Latest would mean, that for highest effectivity, one should avoid Farmerkittens in autumn and winter, thus let them farm in spring and summer and do everything else in autumn/winter. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seasons only have an influence on the catnip production of fields. The farmer job is not affected by the weather.

It is best to not change your kittens very much, because of the bonuses they'll get when they gather enough experience. See for example [here](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Game+Mechanics#Census) or [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184469/should-i-force-my-kittens-to-do-the-same-job-forever?rq=1) question. It is not harmful if you've got a negative catnip production during winter, as long as there is enough produced and stored during spring/summer/autumn. So have enough fields and just a couple of farmers (I believe I've had 2 to 4 farmers, and as many fields as I could buy, and I had an overflow of catnip).

Edit:  The default [formula](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Resources) for the production is the following:

```
perTick = (building output * season modifier + job output * upgrades * happiness) * building % effects + automatic effects - consumption * consumption % effects
```

You see that the season modifier is only multiplied with building output, not with the job output.

Comment: Easiest strategy I've found is to make sure my catnip intake in any one normal season is higher than my winter losses.  So 1 stocked up Autumn can pay for 1 Winter depletion, and I have all of Spring and most of Summer to spend any extra catnip on fields, pastures, or wood as I like.

Comment: So for pure savety, catnip production should not drop under 0 in -90% (cold winter). Effectiveness is a little more complicate, a cold spring (-65% i think?) must produce enaugh catnip to provide a stock for cold winter (-90%), if winter is (-)income.