# How do I change my kittens' jobs?

Tags: kittens-game

In the Small Village, I see a Census that tells me the following information for each of my kittens:

> [:3] NAME NAME - JOB
>   age: AGE
>   SKILL1 (X%) job1
>   SKILL2 (Y%) job2

But I don't know how to get my kittens into the job they are best at. How are kittens assigned to jobs?

Comment: Wondered myself the same for quite some time. But every time I was too lazy to check the code or ask it here. And after some time, you do not switch jobs anymore, so you don't care. Anyway, thanks for asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main section, above the census, is where you increase or decrease the number of kittens on a given job. You don't get fine-grained control over which kittens are doing which job, but you don't really need it; removing a kitten from a job using the [-] button always removes the kitten who is least skilled at it (of those working at that job right now), and adding a free kitten always adds the free kitten with the highest skill in it. As of 0.9.9.2, you can remove a specific kitten from their job when you unlock the Census, but assigning still always assigns the most-skilled kitten.

Note that [your kittens can be skilled in more jobs than display](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184478/50582), so you may not always be able to tell at a glance, but under most circumstances, [your kittens shouldn't be changing jobs too often anyway](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184483/50582).